# jQuery uploadify change file name as it is being uploaded.

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I am using uploadify (a jQuery plugin) to upload files as I am adding clients to my DB.

I would like to attach files to clients. The issue #1 is that the client is a new client so it has not been added to the DB just yet. I have overcome this by getting the next Client_ID in the DB.

NOW the real issue is that all files that are uploaded should be prepended with this ID...something like:
(29) ---i would like the parenthesis as an added open and close of the client_ID----I have searched on stackoverflow and uploadify.com but can't make heads or tails on how to do this.

I NEED TO DO IT VIA JS, because of the fact that I am using the PHP elsewhere in my application and I don't want to change it, if at all possible.

**SOME CODE:**
here is the jQuery thus far

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploader/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'uploader/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'uploader/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : 'clientFiles',
    'buttonText'  : 'Attachments',
    'removeCompleted' : false,
    'multi'          : true,
    'auto'      : true
  });
```

PHP that gets next Client_ID

```
$sql = "SELECT Client_ID FROM clients";
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $nextClientID= mysql_num_rows($result)+1;
```

THANKS for ANY HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to return $targetPath from your uploadify.php file, like this --

`echo $targetPath`

And please remove echo '1'

And now you have to get the renamed file name. You can get this in onUploadSuccess function.
onUploadSuccess() takes three parameters (file, data, response),

where file gives you the actual name of file you browsed through your computer, and data gives you the renamed file name which you generated through your uploadify.php code as per your requirement.

So you can try the below code --

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        alert('Renamed file name is - ' + data);
    }
```

I hope this will help out. One of my friend told me this, and I got my work done then :)

Comment: This is correct. Make sure to use the onUploadSuccess event, and not the onUploadComplete, as 'data' is not an argument for that event.

Answer (score -1):

add to JS

```
onComplete: function(file, tmpname){
 alert(tmpname);
}
```

Add to

uploadify.php

```
die( $temp_name );
```

Comment: that does not seem to work at all. Maybe you can give me some more details. Or adapt it to my code.

Comment: onComplete is not a valid event. THe correct event is onUploadSuccess(file, data, response) http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/